# VB.NET Filtering ListItems Problem

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to filter a ListBox based on the presence of a string. Basically, if there is a ListItem that doesn't contain the string then I want to remove all ListItems that do contain the string.  Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim Item As ListItem
For Each Item In CtheList.Items
    If Item.Text.IndexOf("W:") = -1 Then
        CtheList.Items.Remove(Item)
     End If
 Next
```

Which is apparently a no-no as it generates the error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I have also tried:

```
Dim Item As ListItem
For Each Item In CtheList.Items
    If Item.Text.IndexOf("W:") = -1 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To CtheList.Items.Count - 1
            If CtheList.Items.Item(i).Text.IndexOf("W:") > -1 Then
                CtheList.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next
```

Which generates an index out of range exception.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing your loop, i.e. start from the end of the list. That way, deleting items won't shift the index of the remaining items you still have to check (which is the cause of your out of range exception).

The first way causes a problem because you're modifying the list while iterating over it. And that is, as you said, a big no-no.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the way to do it, but unfortunately still causes the Collection was modified error.  +1 for your help though.

Comment: Yes, your first way will always cause this error. You're simply not allowed to modify the object you're iterating over. I was talking about reversing the loop in your second way.

Comment: Also in my second example I am still modifying the list while iterating over it, just in a 2nd loop.  My solution is below, but you still get the check mark as you led me to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When removing items from a list there are a couple of options. As you've discovered, modifying the collection in a foreach loop isn't going to work. A for loop that counts down is the answer as @balpha mentioned.

Another option is to store a list of items in a separate list, then iterate over that to remove items from the original list. Yet another option is to use LINQ.

Sample list:

```
Dim stringList As New List(Of String)
stringList.Add("W:foo")
stringList.Add("bar")
stringList.Add("barW:")
stringList.Add("foo")
```

**Reverse For Loop**

```
For i As Integer = stringList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If stringList(i).IndexOf("W:") > -1 Then stringList.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

**ForEach with 2 Lists**

```
Dim removeList As New List(Of String)
' store items to remove here
For Each s As String In stringList
    If s.IndexOf("W:") > -1 Then removeList.Add(s)
Next
' remove stored items here
For Each s As String In removeList
    stringList.Remove(s)
Next
```

**LINQ**

In this snippet I filter on IndexOf = -1 instead of > -1 to keep what I want rather than filter what I don't want.

```
stringList = stringList.Where(Function(s) s.IndexOf("W:") = -1).ToList()
```

Comment: +1 for your insight.  Unfortunately no LINQ for me as this is .NET 1.1 but still good to know.

Comment: Something to look forward to then :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on balpha's help above, this is what I ultimately did:

```
Dim StringPresent As Boolean = False
Dim Item As ListItem

For Each Item In CtheList.Items
    If Item.Text.IndexOf("W:") = -1 Then
        StringPresent = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If StringPresent = True Then
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = CtheList.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If CtheList.Items.Item(i).Text.IndexOf("W:") > -1 Then
            CtheList.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Isn't having two passes through this redundant? If you're going to loop through it anyway then you might as well do it all in one pass. Your 2nd loop alone, without the boolean check, is sufficient.

Comment: Actually, on second glance, my code is correct.  I am only filtering out the ListItems with a "W" if there is a ListItem that doesn't contain a "W".  My 2nd loop alone would get rid of all "W" ListItems, regardless of whether a non-W ListItem is present. Updated example again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you filter the items before they are placed in the listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose the filter string is a textbox string and you want to filter your listbox according to the text changed in textbox. Let the name of the textbox is `TB_Filter`.

Place this line of code from the top of your codes, after `Public Class Form1` to temporary hold your listbox items.

```
Dim TempHoldMyItems As New ArrayList
```

Now use this piece of codes in your form_load event to update the temporary list from your listbox items.

```
TempHoldMyItems.Clear()
TempHoldMyItems.AddRange(listbox1.Items)
```

Ok, Now you can filter your listbox items according to the text in TB_Filter. Use this codes in TB_Filter Text Changed event.

```
listbox1.Items.Clear()
For Each item As String In TempHoldMyItems
    If item.Length >= TB_Filter.Text.Length Then
        If item.Substring(0, TB_Filter.Text.Length) = TB_SearchInSelected.Text Then
            listbox1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This will filter items in listbox1 as you will type in TB_Filter. This will match starting of your items with your filter word in TB_Filter.

By making little changes (i.e. Instead of `substring` you may use `contains` property) to check filter query is contains in item.

```
listbox1.Items.Clear()
For Each item As String In TempHoldMyItems
    If item.Contains(TB_Filter.Text) Then
        listbox1.Items.Add(item)
    End If
Next
```