# Find a part of text in a listbox

Tags: vb.net

I've been given some code to find text that is contained in a listbox but, its not what I need. When the user types in the textbox (which is the search field), they have to type the exact text, not the part of the text. Is there any way to find a part of a value/text in a listbox?

For example, I have a listbox that contains these items:

> 1. data1
> 2. data2

When I type (2) in the search field(textbox/richtextbox), I would like the second item, which contain the '2' value, to be selected.

How can I code this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried? What code do you have that partially works. Additionally, using captial letters at the start of you sentence makes text easier to read.

Comment: You are a new poster so, I've taken the time to make your question readable. Please can you take the time to do this in future posts, it shows a minimum level of effort and encourages viewers to at least read your question.

Comment: Now that people might actually read your question, what will make them think its worth answering? You need to invest at least as much time in asking as you expect answers to take in thier response. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: As your question omits some of the information it refers to and doesn't show any research on your part its in danger of being closed as not a real question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IndexOf`

```
Dim hits = From item In listBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)()
           Where item.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
If hits.Any Then
    listBox1.SelectedItem = hits.First()
End If
```

If you don't want to ignore the case, just use `String.Contains` instead of `String.IndexOf`.

Note that above is a linq query, so it won't work with .NET 2 this way.

Comment: I don't think we should limit our answers to legacy versions unless they are explicitly required by the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the terms you want for your search. For example, Text containing any of the letters in the search text, complete words, not searching symbols, etc. 
You have to do it "manually", there isnt a function to search similar texts.

For example:

```
Private Sub SearchBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchBox.TextChanged
    Dim iFound As Integer = -1

    For i As Integer = 0 To SearchBox.TextLength - 1
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(SearchBox.Text(i)) Then
            iFound = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(SearchBox.Text(i))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If iFound >= 0 Then
        TextBox1.Select(iFound, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your checking if a text box `TextBox1` contains any of the `Chars` in the search box. Thats not what the question asks for.

Comment: @Jodrell In fact, this could be an answer. The question asks for a method of searching parts of the text. Its just an example. With more effort he could use the idea to do it with his own parameters, as I explain on the answer.

Comment: @Jodrell, thank you for all your help guys. im sorry, im doing accident, im asking the same question, sorry and thank you very much Jodrell for editing my question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention that you want to keep other items (which do not match with the search query) in your listbox or not.

If you just want to keep the items in listbox which matches or contains your search query then you can check this answer on stackoverflow.

[Match starting of a string in listbox OR Match some part of a string in listbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165944/vb-net-filtering-listitems-problem/25250608#25250608)