# find a part of text in listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

some people give me codes to find a text/value in listbox, but, not like what i need.
what they share is some codes to find the exact text/value in a listbox, but what i need is some codes to find a part of a value/text that was inside the listbox.
so, when i type the part of the value/text, it will found it.
this is what happened, i have a listbox that contain these items:

1. data1
2. data2

and what i need is when i type (2) in the search field(which is richtextbox), it will found it and select it.
is there any way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275274/find-a-part-of-text-in-a-listbox that you posted a few hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [VB.NET `Contains` function](http://www.dotnetperls.com/contains-vbnet)